OpenGL textrenderer doesn't display English Latin letters
I have this simple code for displaying a given letter:
minimal reproducible example:
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL4;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.awt.TextRenderer;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL4.*;

public class Test extends Frame implements GLEventListener {
     private static int[] vao = new int[1];
    private static int[] vbo = new int[4];

    private static GLCanvas canvas;
    private static GL4 gl;
    private static int WIDTH = 750, HEIGHT = 750;

    private TextRenderer textRenderer;

    public Test() {
        canvas = new GLCanvas();
        canvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        this.add(canvas);
        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        this.setVisible(true);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        gl = (GL4) drawable.getGL();
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        gl.glGenVertexArrays(vao.length, vao, 0);
        gl.glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
        gl.glGenBuffers(vbo.length, vbo, 0);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        textRenderer = new TextRenderer(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
    }

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        String letter = "Й";  // Й works, S doesn't
        textRenderer.beginRendering(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        textRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textRenderer.draw(letter, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
        textRenderer.endRendering();
    }


    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        textRenderer.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {}
}

When letters is "S", nothing is displayed (only black background). However, if I change letters to "Й", it is displayed (white letter Й on a black background).
I don't understand, what could be causing this behavior, why English letters are not displayed?

you do not have error checks for your function calls. maybe if you had the checks, the issue will become more evident?

Has the code been tested for any other letters? Are you sure the pattern is that Latin characters work and non-Latin characters do not? Is there any chance a [mre] could be included so we could try to reproduce the problem?

@user14063792468 Do you mean exceptions? No exceptions are thrown during code execution...

@Yun I tested for English letters, numbers, characters like commas - nothing is displayed. Only Cyrillic letters. That's utterly bizarre! I edited my post, truncated the code somewhat, so that it's as minimal as possible!

Thanks! I'll try to have a look later.

Maybe you are sending it Utf-8 but it's expecting Utf-16, or something encoding-wise?

If you comment out the 2 lines with glEnableVertexAttribArray, does it then work? It does on my machine, otherwise it crashes. I suspect that enabling the vertex attrib arrays without using glVertexAttribPointer causes a undefined behavior-like state. Also, from the docs: "Note that the TextRenderer may cause the vertex and texture coordinate array buffer bindings to change, or to be unbound. This is important to note if you are using Vertex Buffer Objects (VBOs) in your application.", so possibly the textRenderer interferes with the existing vao/vbo too.
